# How to find duplicate entries of an email in a database using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I try to check if an email address exists in my database for 3 time with this code

```
$checkEmail = $_POST['email'];

$query = "SELECT email, count(*) $checkEmail FROM participanti GROUP BY email HAVING $checkEmail = 3";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if ($row = mysql_num_rows($result)){

    if ($row[$checkEmail] == 3) {
        echo "NY";
    }
    else{
```

But on my website it says

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@mail.com FROM participanti GROUP BY email HAVING address@mail.com = 3' at line 1
```

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.  Your syntax error is that you have stuck `$checkEmail` in where your fields go.

Comment: $checkEmail is a value, it should have corresponding column name in the query

Comment: Then how to check if the email from my form already exists in my database ?

Comment: Please, edit your post, so we won't need to scroll horizontally to read it

Comment: @SlowlyDeath Show us the example of the database data and the value of $checkEmail variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT email, count(*) as total 
FROM participanti 
WHERE email = '$checkEmail' 
GROUP BY email 
HAVING total = 3";
```

Comment: Thanks :D It works, but ... this prevents sql injection ? I want a secure code because this code is used with a script that works with money ...

Comment: It DOES NOT prevent SQL Injection. Use parameterized queries:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are giving the column an Invalid name.

You should use something like `CntOfEmails` or such

so something like

```
$query = "SELECT email, count(*) CntOfEmails FROM participanti GROUP BY email HAVING CntOfEmails = 3";
```